# Java threads extended runnable state

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a nice way that's not CPU intensive to have a Java thread be in the Runnable state for a long period of time, like one hour?

EDIT: I'm trying to reproduce a bug. I'm suspecting a database connection is reset after a period of time, but thread sleep didn't do it. Before I move on to other possible root causes, I want to make sure that a thread in a runnable state also doesn't cause the connection to be reset.

EDIT: I found a workaround which looks like a big fat hack. Posted the answer to my own question if it helps other people at all.

Comment: What's wrong with Thread.sleep()?

Comment: @Sergey Have you seen what a thread's state is when a thread is sleeping?

Comment: If you told us what you are trying to accomplish with that, we could point out alternative solutions ...

Comment: @meriton, question is edited.

Comment: Your OS probably has a policy on how long connections (database or otherwise) can be kept open for. The difference in thread state sounds strange though.

Answer (score 2):

> A thread in the runnable state is
>   executing in the Java virtual machine
>   but it may be waiting for other
>   resources from the operating system
>   such as processor.

Have the processor work on something else :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.  The only way a thread could stay runnable is to be CPU-bound or to be waiting for a higher-priority thread that was CPU-bound.

Answer (score 1):

I think I kind of found a workaround just now.

If I try to connect to a non-existing domain, the thread will be in the running state until the connection times-out (I think this depends on the OS).

```
try {
    new URL("http://thisdomaindoesnotexist.com").
    openConnection().
    getInputStream().
    read();
} 
catch (Exception e) {}
```

On my machine this takes about 20 seconds.

The System.in InputStream also works but my web application doesn't have console input.

Answer (score 0):

If a thread is runnable (at the OS level, there's generally a difference between "runnable" and "actually running on a CPU as we speak"), then at some point sooner or later, the OS will try to give it some CPU time. There's kind of no way round that-- there's not really a category of "runnable but I don't to actually give it any CPU time". A potential option may be to give the thread a low priority: just be clear about what that actually means on your particular system (I've written a little about [thread priorities](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml) and what they really mean on different OS's in case it helps).

Also have a look at [Thread.yield()](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/yield.shtml) -- again, just be aware that it means different things on different OS's.

However, I stress from my comment above-- I wonder if your OS is simply closing connections after a certain time open and/or at a certain scheduled time closing all idle connections, rather than things being dependent on thread state/CPU usage.

Comment: The only thing that's making me think it's the thread state is that if I put my thread to sleep (idle connection), the connection isn't reset. It might be something not related after all. Thanks for your input.